# destructing an object with Incomplete type

Tags: c++

I have read other stackoverflow questions on the subject, yet I am really confused with the incomplete type and this C++ specification paragraph §5.3.5/5 :

> If the object being deleted has incomplete class type at the point of
>   deletion and the complete class has a non-trivial destructor or a
>   deallocation function, the behavior is undefined.

Given an example, .h :

```
template<class T> class my_scoped_ptr
{
private:
    T *t;
public:
    my_scoped_ptr(T * _t) : t(_t) {}
    ~my_scoped_ptr()  {
        typedef char type_must_be_complete[ sizeof(T)? 1: -1 ];
        (void) sizeof(type_must_be_complete);
        delete t;
    }
};

class Holder
{
public:
    Holder();
    ~Holder();
private:
    class Impl;
    my_scoped_ptr<Impl> _mptr;
};
```

.cpp

```
class Holder::Impl {};
Holder::Holder() : _mptr(new Impl) {}
Holder::~Holder() {}
```

How does the non-inline destructor of class Holder suddenly make Impl complete?
Why is the default destructor not sufficient to make the class complete? Why shared_ptr works perfectly well without the need of the destructor?

Comment: About shared_ptr, examine the implementation to see the amazing tricks they pull to work around undefined behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's all about the point of instantiation of `my_scoped_ptr<Impl>::~my_scoped_ptr`.

When you don't provide a user-defined destructor, the default one is defined as soon as the definition of class `Holder` is processed - basically, it's equivalent to defining the destructor in-class:

```
class Holder {
  // ... 
  ~Holder() {}
};
```

This destructor needs to destroy `_mptr` member, so `~my_scoped_ptr` is also instantiated at this point, while `Impl` is still incomplete.

When you explicitly declare the destructor in the header, and define in .cpp file, the instantiation of `~my_scoped_ptr` happens at the point of that definition - and by that time, `Impl` is complete.

`std::shared_ptr` works around this by capturing the deleter at run-time, in its constructor, at the point where it's handed the raw pointer for the first time, and storing it in the control block. You can even assign `std::shared_ptr<Derived>` to `std::shared_ptr<Base>`, and the latter will eventually call the correct destructor, even if non-virtual. `std::shared_ptr` can pull this trick off because it needs to allocate extra storage (for the reference count, among other things) anyway, so it's already somewhat heavyweight. `std::unique_ptr` on the other hand exhibits the same issue as your `my_scoped_ptr`, for all the same reasons.

Comment: In other words, should it become a good practice to always define a destructor in cpp file to have everything, like `Impl`, defined at the point of destruction?

Comment: It wouldn't hurt, I suppose. It's certainly wise when utilizing Pimpl idiom.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't complete in the header file.

`~Holder();` is declaring an external function.

declaring `~Holder() = default;` is equivalent to declaring `~Holder() {}`, which is to say that it's providing a definition of the declared destructor. It cannot do this because the inner `Impl` class has only been declared at this point, not defined.